# Are class-based Swift Constants Forced to be Optional

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

I'm very new to Swift development, so apologise if this is a really silly question - having read Apple's guide, I am surprised by the behaviour I have come across (and a little miffed).

I am creating a really simple class which defines a number of uninitialised constants at the beginning of the class. When the class is initialised, the values are set. It seems as though I cannot do this unless I declare the constants to be optional, even though they are not optional and are all set in the constructor. For example:

```
class TestClass {
    private let urlAddress:String

    init(urlAddress: String) {
        self.urlAddress = getUrlAddressWithProto("http", urlAddress:urlAddress)
    }

    func getUrlAddressWithProto(proto: String, urlAddress:String) -> String {
        return "\(proto)://\(urlAddress)/"
    }
}
```

The function `getUrlAddressWithProto` returns a non-optional String but Xcode throws the error:
    error: variable 'self.urlAddress' used before being initialized

Does anyone have any thoughts firstly on why this is the case and if there is a suitable alternative to declaring all my constants as optional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler probably wants to tell you that you are not allowed to call that function before all non-optional variables are initialized. Sometimes the error messages are not very obvious.

Swift prevents the use of instances that are in an inconsistent state. Swift does not know that the function you call doesn't rely on internal state, so you can't call instance functions before init is done at all.

You have a couple of options, besides marking the variable as optional.

- Turn that function into a class function. Since class functions are not bound to an instance you can call them before the init of the instance is done
- move the code from the function to the initializer
- Turn the variable into an implicitly unwrapped optional. (i.e. `let urlAddress: String!`). You can use that variable as if it were a non-optional variable. Just make sure that you set it during init. If you do something with it while it is nil the program will abort.

Depending on your real code the last one is probably the only viable option.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, the third option is the most suitable to me although the first could also be made to work. (There are multiple initialisers, which is why the use of the function).

Comment: The multiple inits can (and should) all call back to a designated class init. The problem with implicitly unwrapped variables is that they can be set to nil. And if it is, using it will result in a crash.

Comment: Are you suggesting within the same class or in a superclass? My class does not subclass anything else and depending on how the object is initialised controls its behaviour further down the line. Are you suggesting this is bad practice? As long as I ensure my inits instantiate the various constants / variables, it what I am doing not OK?